# Not found for architecture x86_64?

Tags: makefile

I am adding a test suite for a doubly linked list, but when I add the test suite, I get this compiler error:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Test::runTests()", referenced from:
      DoubleLinkedList::Tester() in main.o
  "Test::Test(std::__1::basic_ostream >&)", referenced from:
      DoubleLinkedList::Tester() in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command

I think it has something to do with my makefile but I am unsure.

Here is the makefile

```
dll: main.o 
    g++ -g -std=c++0x  main.o -o dll
main.o: main.cpp DoubleLinkedList.h DoubleLinkedList.hpp Node.h Node.hpp
    g++ -g -std=c++0x -c main.cpp
Test.o: DoubleLinkedList.h Test.cpp
    g++ -g -std=c++0x -c Test.cpp

clean: 
rm *.o lab03
echo clean done
```

Here is the method definition and call from DoubleLinkedList.hpp.

```
 template<typename T>
 void DoubleLinkedList<T>::Tester()

{
  Test myTester(std::cout);
  myTester.runTests();

}
```

Comment: Where do you link `Test.o` into your `dll` binary?

Comment: It's included at the top of the double linked list.hpp which is included at the top of main.cpp

Comment: I assume you mean you are including a `Test.h` header file there? In which case that's not linking. That's compile-time inclusion. You still need to link the `.o` into your binary.

Comment: Update: I added "Test.h" and "Test.cpp" to "main.o: main.cpp DoubleLinkedList.h DoubleLinkedList.hpp Node.h Node.hpp"

Comment: Add it to the `dll` target along with `main.o`.